# IndexError: list index out of range in quick sort algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort, index-error

I'm trying to write a python script of "quick sort" algorithm.

This is my code :

```
def quick_sort(sequence):
    pivot = sequence.pop()
    greater =[]
    lower = []

    for i in sequence:
            if sequence[i] > pivot : 
                greater.append(sequence[i])
            else:
                lower.append(sequence[i])
    return lower + pivot + greater 

sequence = [1,6,3,5,9,6,0,9,3,5,12,37,33,65,55,454,45,len("good")]
quick_sort(sequence)
```

but I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 7, in quick_sort
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please can someone help me to fix that error?

Comment: Just gonna say: `sorted(sequence)` is all you need

Comment: ``for i in sequence:`` is already iterating the contents of the list, not their index.

Comment: Is this a project, or do you just want to sort a list?

Comment: @AnnZen   No, I just want to sort a list .

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, this question only wants to sort a list. It is very simple. Either do this:

```
lst = sorted(lst)
```

or, if you don't want to use a equal operator:

```
lst.sort()
```

will sort it automatically.

Comment: But ! I'm beginner ! and   I want to use the concept of quick sort ,

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in these two lines:

```
        for i in sequence:
            if sequence[i] > pivot :
```

In Python, `for x in _list` will iterate over the *values* of `_list`, not the indices. In your example, that means that at some point `i == 37` and the `if` condition attempts to access `sequence[37]`, which is out of range. There are two ways to fix this:

1. `for i in range(len(sequence)):` will give you the indices.
2. Simply using the value of `i` rather than using it as an index (also in the lines where you append). Personally, this would be my preference - overall it looks neater to me.

Also, note that `lower` and `greater` are lists, while `pivot` is an integer, so you can't do `lower + pivot + greater` - you'll have to wrap `pivot` in a list first (`lower + [pivot] + greater`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation of Quick Sort some time ago, might help you to design and test your own Quick Sort algorithm:

```
import random
from typing import TypeVar, List
from scipy import stats

T = TypeVar('T')


def quick_sort(input_list: List[T]) -> List[T]:
    """"
    Returns an ascending sorted list;
    Input variable is an integer or float array;
    Theoretical Complexity: O(N*Log N) Time and O(N) Memory
    """

    sort(input_list, 0, len(input_list) - 1)
    return input_list


def sort(input_list: List[T], start_index: int, end_index: int) -> None:
    """Recursively sorts the two pivot-divided sublists;"""
    if start_index >= end_index:
        return
    pivot_index = partition(input_list, start_index, end_index)
    sort(input_list, start_index, pivot_index - 1)
    sort(input_list, pivot_index + 1, end_index)


def partition(input_list: List[T], start_index: int, end_index: int) -> int:
    """
    Returns the end index; Partitions a list into two sublists;
    """
    pivot = input_list[start_index]

    i, j = start_index + 1, end_index

    while i <= j:
        while input_list[i] < pivot and i < end_index:
            i += 1
        while input_list[j] > pivot:
            j -= 1

        if i < j:
            temp = input_list[i]
            input_list[i] = input_list[j]
            input_list[j] = temp
            i += 1
            j -= 1
        else:
            break

    input_list[start_index] = input_list[j]
    input_list[j] = pivot

    return j


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Creates a dash line string and a new line for in between the tests.
    delimiter = "-" * 70 + "\n"

    # Generates a random integer list.
    test_list_integer = random.sample(range(-100, 100), 15) * 3
    print(f"""The unsorted integer array is:
        {test_list_integer}""")
    print(delimiter)

    # Generates a random float list.
    test_list_float = stats.uniform(0, 100).rvs(45)
    print(f"""The unsorted float array is:
        {test_list_float}""")
    print(delimiter)

    # Sample float/integer test list for input.
    integer_float_input = list(test_list_integer + test_list_float)

    # Sample float/integer test list for output.
    integer_float_output = sorted(integer_float_input)

    sorting_algorithms = [
        ("Quick Sort", quick_sort)
    ]

    # Testing
    for description, func in sorting_algorithms:
        if (func(integer_float_input.copy()) == integer_float_output):
            print(f"{description} Test was Successful.")
        else:
            print(f"{description} Test was not Successful.")
        print(f"""{description} (Integer):
            {func(test_list_integer.copy())}""")
        print(f"""{description} (Float):
            {func(test_list_float.copy())}""")
        print(delimiter)
```

#### Prints

```
The unsorted integer array is:
        [-37, 74, -9, 58, 96, 82, 32, 94, -77, -54, -13, -10, -82, 57, 6, -37, 74, -9, 58, 96, 82, 32, 94, -77, -54, -13, -10, -82, 57, 6, -37, 74, -9, 58, 96, 82, 32, 94, -77, -54, -13, -10, -82, 57, 6]
----------------------------------------------------------------------

The unsorted float array is:
        [ 4.46747765 21.96382498 21.00086463 49.15870339 95.19971828 94.5108942
  1.88156027 49.1355604  78.5032007  32.4662292  15.0415828  75.04492651
 29.491373    4.02412264 22.34068707 97.39317437 27.64026964 85.52244153
  0.53119133 16.63664738 86.79522363 33.07979585 88.50108333 57.40225507
 72.25826399 99.82793291 99.84493522 15.96858729 33.58735178  1.70611819
 68.07308792 46.09522364 21.42563941  5.55154387 10.60707898 92.78939519
 77.01866529 14.12783987 87.17625745 52.8310454  19.39884535 94.30883322
 96.14062517 45.56022192 24.39705178]
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Quick Sort Test was Successful.
Quick Sort (Integer):
            [-82, -82, -82, -77, -77, -77, -54, -54, -54, -37, -37, -37, -13, -13, -13, -10, -10, -10, -9, -9, -9, 6, 6, 6, 32, 32, 32, 57, 57, 57, 58, 58, 58, 74, 74, 74, 82, 82, 82, 94, 94, 94, 96, 96, 96]
Quick Sort (Float):
            [ 0.53119133  1.70611819  1.88156027  4.02412264  4.46747765  5.55154387
 10.60707898 14.12783987 15.0415828  15.96858729 16.63664738 19.39884535
 21.00086463 21.42563941 21.96382498 22.34068707 24.39705178 27.64026964
 29.491373   32.4662292  33.07979585 33.58735178 45.56022192 46.09522364
 49.1355604  49.15870339 52.8310454  57.40225507 68.07308792 72.25826399
 75.04492651 77.01866529 78.5032007  85.52244153 86.79522363 87.17625745
 88.50108333 92.78939519 94.30883322 94.5108942  95.19971828 96.14062517
 97.39317437 99.82793291 99.84493522]
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Reference

[Quick Sort Algorithm (Python)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229772/quick-sort-algorithm-python)

Here is a good [code review of the implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/229777/190910).